# What is the dual $(U{}_f\times_g V)^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a given field $\mathbb K$. Take two linear maps $f:U\longrightarrow W$ and $g:V\longrightarrow W$ and define:

$$U{}_{f}\times_g V:=\{(u, v)\in U\times V: f(u)=g(v)\}.$$

This is clearly a vector subspace of the direct product space $U\times V$. What can we say about the dual vector space $(U{}_{f}\times_g V)^*$?

I know that $$(U\times V)^*\simeq U^*\times V^*$$ as @Kenny Laus pointed out. For $U{}_f\times_g V$ we can't realize $U$ and $V$ as vector subspaces although we can consider $\mathsf{Ker}(f)$ and $\mathsf{ker}(g)$ as vector subspaces.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Dual is a contravariant functor that preserves limits, so it preserves finite products, i.e. $(U \times V)^* = U^* \times V^*$.

Comment: @KennyLau But when we dualize the pullback diagram turns into a pushout diagram, right? I don't remember now but such pushout will be a quotient of $U^*\times V^*$ by a vector subspace?

Comment: @KennyLau Dual preserve products because they happen to also be coproducts.

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes, finite products and finite coproducts coincide.

Comment: But more general limits need not be colimits of anything interesting.

Comment: The pushout is $(U^*\times V^*)/S$ where $S=\langle (S\circ f, -S\circ g): S\in W^*\rangle$. But I was expecting something more practical.